# fprintf printing weird characters in a for loop

Tags: c, file-io, printf

I have a program which determines the value of a int, fc1, in a for loop many times, and outputs it to a file using fprintf.

```
for (i=0; i<80; i++)
{
    fc1 = somefunction(); // this function determines if fc is 0 or 1

    // printing fc1 to stdout
    printf("%d\n", fc1);

    // printing output to file
    fprintf(out, "%d ", fc1);
}
```

Whenever I run the loop 80 times or fewer, the file output is like expected:

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

However, once I loop it 81 times or more, the file output is garbage..

```
‱‰‱‰‱‱‰‰‰‰‱‰‱‱‱‱‰‰‰‱‱‰‱‱‱‰‱‰‰‱‱‱‰‰‱‰‰‱‰‱‰‱‰‱‱‰‱‱‰‰‰‱‰‱‰‱‰‰‱‱‰‰‱‰‰‰‰‰‰‱‱‱‰‱‰‱‰‱‰‰‱
```

somehow it will end up outputting U+2030 and U+2031 even though I was printing an integer.

When I try

```
fprintf(out, "%d", fc1);
fputc(' ', out); // i changed the fprintf to fprintf the int and fputc the space
```

nothing changes too, this problem still happens, but when I do

```
fprintf(out, "%d", fc1);
fputc(' ', out);
fputc(' ', out);
```

somehow it works! and the output will have 2 spaces,

```
1  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my usage of fprintf?

**Some additional info**

- All variables are int
- File pointer is set up properly
- fc1 definitely has 1 or 0 every time the loop runs (because I print the value to stdout and I can see its 0 or 1)
- GNU GCC Compiler, MingW CodeBlocks 12.11 on Windows 7

EDIT:

here is the somefunction()

```
int fc(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    int bits = a*10000+b*1000+c*100+d*10+e;
    switch(bits)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 100:
        case 101:
        case 111:
        case 1000:
        case 1001:
        case 1110:
        case 1111:
        case 10000:
        case 10001:
        case 10010:
        case 10100:
        case 10110:
        case 11010:
        case 11110:
            return 1;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

and the way I open the file pointer out

```
FILE *out = fopen("out.txt", "w");
```

I open the output file with notepad on windows

Comment: Post `somefunction` or all we can do is guess. There is no doubt you are either overfowing a storage size or an array in your loop. You can loop and print all values with `%d` between `2147483648 - 2147483647` with an int and never have any issue, but as soon as you cause your int to exceed `above/below` either you have overflowed and strayed off into `undefined behavior` unless you handle it.

Comment: Can you show how do you open your `out` file?  What flags do you use?  Also, what software do you use to read the `out` file?  Does it support UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: if you open that file with notepad++ or something they might infer encoding which causes your problem. try forcing viewing in iso-8859-1 or ASCII...

Comment: To everyone, I know now that this might be just an encoding issue, but do you guys have any idea why it specifically screws up after looping 80 times?

Comment: @Christopher: Not specifically, the used function [`IsTextUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672(v=vs.85).aspx) is a heuristic black-box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the ASCII-table, especially the entries for

1. space: 0x20
2. '0': 0x30
3. '1': 0x31

Your program seems to do everything right, but your viewer is *too smart* to leave well-enough alone.
I really hate programs being so smart they do something completely idiotic.
(like guessing a plain ASCII-file is UTF-16)

Still, there is hope: Either you can force your viewer to use a specific encoding at opening or during viewing, or you can just switch to a different one.

BTW: Notepad on windows uses the heuristic black-box function [`IsTextUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672(v=vs.85).aspx) to divine whether text is unicode or not.

Comment: Hello! Does that mean that there is actually no problem? How do I force notepad to view it the way I want it? And if I do a fscanf(in, "%d", &somevar), will I be able to read the ones and zeroes properly?

Comment: Notepad? Ok, just choose open, and select the proper encoding in the combo-box at the bottom (ANSI / ASCII / ISO-whatever / OEM should all work).